# QGIS html annotation relative paths

Tags: qgis, html, file-path

I find the QGIS html annotation tool is very useful for quickly accessing a combination of key data attributes and photos. I am having trouble using relative paths for images.

This doesn't work:

```
<img src="[% html_src %]" />
```

a.k.a.

```
<img src="/Image/Picture.JPG" />
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to employ a QgsProject.instance() in the QGIS Macro option under project properties. I don't know html very well, so I'm wondering how I could link the relative pathname to the project path using something like this:

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
UriFile = str(proj.fileName())
pathname = str(os.path.dirname(UriFile))
```

How can I concatenate this in the html display option?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can solve this problem, if you adapt your situation, like in the example bellow.

Presuming this is how it looks the vector layer's attribute table:

[image]

Here's the images' storing folder:

[image]

And this is the **annotation.html** :

```
<b> [% "name" %] </b>
<br />
<img src=file:///c:/temp/images/[% "img_src" %].png />
```

Eventually, here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the attribute table contains a relative pathname, but the html display still requires the root folder c:/temp/ to be defined. Is it possible to adapt this to a situation where the only information known about the image source is relative to the directory containing the QGIS project?

Answer (score 0):

If your imagesources are stored in the attribute table of a vector layer you can use the field calculator to add a new virtual field. In this field you can store i.e. the path to the project folder (can be found in the variables section):

[image: add project folder field]

Your annotation html would then look somthing like this:

```
<img src="file:///[% "root" %]/[% "img_path" %]">
```